# Convert .Caf file to more standard format programatically in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession, caf

I know this has been asked around, but couldn't find a straight answer.
My App uploads .caf files from ios to Webserver, where .caf isn't a recognized format. What Should I do programatically in iOS to turn it into mp3, .wav..etc before uploading to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** : I had the same problem and solution is given below

I had same issue, As `.caf isn't a recognized format in ISS 6.0` or greater (not sure about which ISS) so u `convert into base64` then save in server as `.cab file`

When retrieving again convert form `.cab to .caf` file

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an easy way to do this. So, I ended up downloading caf players on my windows machine.